# rails - parameters when displaying acts as taggable on with tag.scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, strong-parameters, acts-as-taggable-on

So, I have a Post model with acts as taggable and Tag model where I defined a scope predefined tags called 'categories' set to true like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :categories, -> { where(categories: true) }
end
```

I now want to display a form where my users can choose at least one and up to three predefined tags (Tag.categories), and my field form like so:

```
<%= f.label :tags, 'Categories' %>
<% Tag.categories.each do |tag| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "post[tag_list][]", tag.name, @post.tag_list.include?(tag.name) %> 
  <%= tag.name %>
<% end %>

<%= f.label :tags %>
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
```

The idea is that I want my users to choose up to 3 predefined tags (categories), and at the same time add how many tags as they wish. I have 10 predefined tags which I seeded to Tag table and set their category to true.

It works fine for the normal tags (when users add their own tags, or if they tags are already exists, will just update the taggings_count), but my predefined tags are not saving/updating the count.

In the log, the parameter only show `"tag_list"=>"tag1"`, where tag1 is a tag entered by user, but not getting the tag.category selected "Travel" which was seeded to Tag table, thus not updating the tagging_count of "Travel".

I've looked around but couldn't find answers that work, and oh - I'm a RoR beginner.

I'm using acts as taggable on 3.4, with Rails 4.2.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm struggling to figure out how to force the use of predefined tags too